# JVM Level Clustering in Netty Server 4.0

Tags: jvm, cluster-computing, netty

This is my first question in this forum, so kindly forgive me for my mistakes.
Now, my query is regarding clustering in Netty Server 4.0.

We have one solution which was designed and developed in Netty Server. That time it was using multiple instances in a way so that clients were not effected if the sessions are not shared among them.
Now, in a different project while using the same solution we have come across a situation where we need to share and synchronized the JVM within multiple instances. Since, netty itself does not support JVM level clustering we are looking for a framework which will support Netty to run in cluster mode.

We are not supposed to put lot of efforts in re-writing the Netty Server code and other business login as it is serving the same purpose but we are looking for a configuration based framework to support clustering with Netty Server.
Some configuration based tutorial are really appreciated.

Thanks in advance and looking forward for responses.

Regards
Sid

Comment: What sort of synchronization do you need?

Comment: Hello Eran, We need memory/heap sharing among different nodes where Netty Servers are running. So that we can get connection objects and other Data Structures objects on other nodes.

Comment: Sharing data between JVMs can be done with memcached, Chronical Map, Terracotta and the like, depending on your needs, but you can't share connections. I think you want to use a load balancer right?